# Fluent Api Composite Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this configuration:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    public int TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string Rsocial { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public int Rut { get; set; }
    public List<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}
```

and in the context class I wrote this configuration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
             .HasKey(cl => new { cl.ClienteId, cl.Empresa.EmpresaId})
             .HasName("PK_cliente");
```

I get this error:

> An error occurred creating the DB.
> System.ArgumentException: The expression 'cl => cl.Empresa.EmpresaId' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')

Comment: The fields to make up your composite primary key **must be** from the entity itself - **NOT** from a referenced entity! You can use any combination of `ClienteId`, `TipoDocumento` and `Rsocial`- but you **CANNOT** reference `Empresa` and use a field from that entity in the composite PK

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation for the OwnsOne method. Your Cliente owns one Empresa. It won’t help your primary key issue, but it looks like it may help you relate these 2 classes properly.

Comment: I think i will put a Empresa ID field in the class Cliente and i will mark it manually as a Foreign Key from the the Table Empresa and this will fix the problem (i think).

Its normal to use a Foreign Key as Primary Key, i was thinking that EF do that automatically.

Comment: Yes, the Cliente entity will require the EmpresaID if the PK is the combination of the two IDs, just as the Cliente table will require it. You set it as part of the Key as well as the FK to the associated Empresa.